# Is there a way to split only some <div> tags into two columns?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to split only particular divs into two columns?

My css file looks like following

```
#views-form
 {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#views-form .item-list {
  list-style-position: inside;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

But it results in spliting all divs inside of the form into two columns.

```
<form id="views-form">
   <div></div>
   <div class="item-list"></div>
   <div class="item-list"></div>
   <div class="item-list"></div>
   <div class="item-list"></div>
   <div class="item-list"></div>
    ....
   <div></div>
</form>
```

I need to split div tags with class "item-list" into two columns. Unfortuntely I am not able to wrap "item-list" divs in some other tag.

Comment: which div you want split into two col exactly

Comment: Can you use other solutions than `columns` property?

Comment: I want to split only the divs with class="item-list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use flex?

```css
.views-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.views-form > div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 20px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 10px;
}

.views-form > .item-list {
  flex-basis: caLc(50% - 20px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<form class="views-form">
   <div>...</div>
   <div class="item-list">a</div>
   <div class="item-list">b</div>
   <div class="item-list">c</div>
   <div class="item-list">d</div>
   <div class="item-list">e</div>
   <div>...</div>
</form>
```

IMHO CSS `columns` rule is only useful for copy text, but not for presenting subsequent containers in several columns. This is because of the reading order of `columns` rule (down first, right second). This will force the user to scroll down till the end of the first column and then scroll up to the beginning of the second column. Nobody wants that. If you carefully read the [MDN guide on Multicol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Basic_Concepts_of_Multicol), you will see that all the examples are text only.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work in Firefox: See: [Browser Compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-span#Browser_compatibility) on [MDN `columns-span` doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-span), [this bugreport](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616436)

```css
#views-form {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#views-form > div {
  -webkit-column-span: all; 
  -moz-column-span: all;
  column-span: all;
}

#views-form > .item-list {
  list-style-position: inside;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;

}
```

```html
<form id="views-form">
   <div>1</div>
   <div class="item-list">2</div>
   <div class="item-list">3</div>
   <div class="item-list">4</div>
   <div class="item-list">5</div>
   <div class="item-list">6</div>
   <div>7</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your code perfectly worked for me. Just one question: is it poassible to align divs vertically, rather than horizontally?

Comment: @badm For this you should post a new question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this Like that

```css
.two-col
 {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#views-form .item-list {
  list-style-position: inside;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;

}
```

```html
<form id="views-form">
   <div>1</div>
   <div class="two-col">
     <div class="item-list">2</div>
     <div class="item-list">3</div>
     <div class="item-list">4</div>
     <div class="item-list">5</div>
     <div class="item-list">6</div>
   </div>
   <div>7</div>
</form>
```